# Cannot redirect the page after exporting and saving the excel file

Tags: c#, asp.net, export-to-excel, httpresponse

```
ExportToCSVFile(DtExcel);
Response.ContentType = "Application/x-msexcel";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + GetCustomerUserID() + "_UserList.csv");
Response.Write(ExportToCSVFile(DtExcel));
// Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
Response.Redirect("Redirect_Url_ExportToExcel.aspx", false);
// Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
// Response.End();
```

hi

I am exporting and saving the excel file. After saving the file the page is still doing some processing. To abort that processing i need to redirect the page. If I' redirect the page the SaveFileDilaog doesn't appear. If it appears at that time the page does not redirect. Please give some solution.

Comment: how can i run this method in a separate thread? Any idea

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot redirect from the same page as you changed the response.contenttype. This is what I have done. I created a method that calls a handler, and a handler does the download (in your case it will create the CSV then download it). From my base page, I call the method (to call a handler) then call a redirect. Hope it helps.